# simple rating code via PHP

Tags: php

i have some questions. i used of list/menu for rating like this:

```
 <select>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
```

in my db2 i have username and rate that db2 fetch username when anyone register in register page of my site.
1. i need when user click on a number, automatically send the rate to db without using of button. 
2. how i can use of multiple ratings? i mean is some one like to rate more that one item, how can store multiple results? there is a list for each item
 
3. how i can fill my current user rating? i mean when i insert a rate into my db, db make a new record and username column is empty, i need fill rate of current username, i want to recognize who rated.

Comment: I would suggest you use [radio buttons](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio) for selecting a rating.

Comment: @TanuelMategi ok, can u answer my questions?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place where people help you, not where they teach you everything. you are asking for way too much here. first of all, i suggest you learn about [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). The [Jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) can help you. And then you need to learn how to design a database with references

Comment: You could start with simple courses at w3schools or codeacademy or Udemy where they give a graded course on building simple web applications with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I' ll try to give you some hints.

1) You need to use AJAX for this. At change event send the value to database.

2) Your rating table will have a separate column for each answer/rate and like previous you will bind the change event on every select boxes you want.

3) At the previous stages you can simple save username as well as the rate.

```
Rating_table
username    question     rate
```